# Extracting values from json converted from xml complicated schema nodejs/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, xml

Hi I have following xml repsonse from soap based ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:RequestHeader
         soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next"
         soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"
         xmlns:ns1="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201802">
      <ns1:networkCode>123456</ns1:networkCode>
      <ns1:applicationName>DfpApi-Java-2.1.0-dfp_test</ns1:applicationName>
    </ns1:RequestHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getAdUnitsByStatement xmlns="https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201802">
      <filterStatement>
        <query>WHERE parentId IS NULL LIMIT 500</query>
      </filterStatement>
    </getAdUnitsByStatement>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

using xml2js I parsed it to json

```
var parser=ew xml2js.Parser({explicitArray: false, trim: true});
parser.parseString(bdy, (err, result)=>{
     console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
```

I get following json values

```
 {
  "soapenv:Envelope": {
    "-xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
    "-xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "-xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "soapenv:Header": {
      "ns1:RequestHeader": {
        "-xmlns:ns1": "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201802",
        "-soapenv:actor": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next",
        "-soapenv:mustUnderstand": "0",
        "ns1:networkCode": "123456",
        "ns1:applicationName": "DfpApi-Java-2.1.0-dfp_test"
      }
    },
    "soapenv:Body": {
      "getAdUnitsByStatement": {
        "-xmlns": "https://www.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201802",
        "filterStatement": { "query": "WHERE parentId IS NULL LIMIT 500" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is save individual values to use them. For example i want

```
to save 
var t1=-xlmns     
or 
var t2=ns1:networkCode
```

Please let me know the best way to do...I was thinking of creating json object but not sure how to do with this json...let me know the best way to go about it.

Comment: you want to extract the value of xmlns or networkCode right?

Comment: Yes -xlmns at least that I need too extract

Comment: you can use xpath for that https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath